# Changing the background image of HBox

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, background-image, hbox

I have assigned a logo image of my software to HBox as follows -

```
<mx:HBox id="logoBox" width="98%" textAlign="left" backgroundSize="100%" horizontalAlign="left" height="18%" backgroundImage="images/img_header_new_3-bg.jpg" verticalAlign="bottom" backgroundColor="#1573A4">
```

Now I need to change the backgroundImage to some other image on a event. 
How to achieve this? I am not able to refer backgroundImage property using the id 'logoBox'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BackgroundImage is a style of HBox. After the component has been created you need to set the style like so:

```
logoBox.setStyle("backgroundImage","images/img_header_new_2-bg.jpg");
```